# Trying to get data from API products with Angular

Tags: c#, json, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am getting data from API but not how it is supposed to be.

I have entity "product" which has property

```
public string ArtId { get; set; }
```

and in JSON file that I used for seeding template database property is `ArtId`

but in API when I get data from database `ArtId` starts with lowercase "a" ->  `artId`.

Now in my typescript interface for product this property is also `ArtId` but I can't use it like `{{p.ArtId}}` I must use it like

```
{{p.artId}}
```

I think I need to change something in JSON configuration but I don't know what.

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: Newtonsoft library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the naming strategy of the contract resolver to the

```
ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() 
                   { 
                      NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy() 
                   }
```

in the configurations.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking.